# can you let me know what im doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

```js
    var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    var guess;
    while(guess !== target){
        guess=  Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        console.log(target);
        target = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    }
    console.log(guess);
```

So im currently aplying for a bootcamp of programming, but im stuck in this quest!

they ask this:

> Your editor currently has a variable declared target to which a random number between 0 and 10 will be assigned. Print the target to the console.
> Write a small program which will keep guessing numbers between 0 and 10 and printing them until the guessed number is the same as the target.

and the error that the console gives me is

> Make sure you initialized the variable guess

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: Don't modify `target` in the loop.

Comment: Its a bit weird for target to change after every guess.  You could just keep guessing 1 and eventually get it.

Comment: Also, you are supposed to print `target` before the loop and `guess`, not `target` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right operator in the while-function is '!=' insted of '!=='.

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify `target` inside the loop. It's hard to hit a moving target. Also, a `do/while` loop would avoid the uninitialized variable:

```js
var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
console.log(target);
var guess;
do {
    guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    console.log(guess);
} while (guess !== target);
```

Comment: Ty Johnny, but still gives me the same error

Comment: Maybe the judges want you to initialize `guess` to something - even though it is unnecessary with this code. `var guess = 0;`

Comment: I did that, and the erro it appears after is guess: should be a integer Radom number

Comment: Ty for your help, I did got it now!